# Trying to use regex_replace to extract numbers

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aginity

I have a column with dma codes. They are either in the following two formats:

a) 100123

b) ="100123"

I am trying to get them all in format a).

I have tried using NULLIF(regexp_replace(column_name, '\D','','g'), '')::numeric

But I am not able to use the proper syntax.

SELECT
    ds.from_date
    ,state_map.state_name as state
    ,dma_region_name
    ,zip_map.dma_name as dma_name
    ,regexp_replace(dma_region_id,'','[0-9]')
    ,postal_code_name
     ,search_codes_map.is_sourcecode
    ,search_codes_map.geo
    ,search_codes_map.tactic
    ,search_codes_map.engine
    ,search_codes_map.strategy
    ,search_codes_map.device
    ,search_codes_map.campaign_type
    ,search_codes_map.keyword_type
    ,search_codes_map.intent_bucket
    ,search_codes_map.match_type
    ,search_codes_map.test_indicator
    ,SUM(ds.clicks) AS clicks
    ,SUM(ds.impr) AS impressions
    ,SUM(ds.cost) AS cost
    ,SUM(ds.phone_calls) AS phone_calls
    ,SUM(ds.dialogtech_calls) AS dialogtech_calls
    ,SUM(ds.ebrc_completion) AS ebrc_completion
    ,0 as smart_phone_leads
    ,0 as smart_web_leads
    ,0 as smart_leads
    ,0 as smart_agent_appointments
    ,0 as smart_oles
    ,0 as phone_enrollment
    ,0 as smart_sales
    ,0 as smart_paid_sales
FROM digital.uhg_mr_is_search ds
-- IS campaign-to-source_code mapper
LEFT JOIN uhg_part_b.v_is_search_manual_dims_dedupe search_codes_map
       ON ds.campaign = search_codes_map.campaign_name
-- Bring in state acronym 
-- Yang: Note there's a very small number of cases when we do NOT have state name but do have DMA name in raw data. Didn't map them to state as we do not have a dma id mapper in reftables
LEFT JOIN reftables.us_states state_map ON ds.state_name = state_map.state_name
LEFT JOIN reftables.zip_dma_map zip_map ON RIGHT(ds.dma_region_id,3)= zip_map.dma_code 
-- LEFT JOIN reftables.dcm_dma_map DMA ON dma.dma_code = map.dma_code

WHERE from_date >= '2018-07-01' 
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17

;

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `replace()`?

```
select replace(replace(dma, '"', ''), '=') as dma_type_a
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. For others trying to use this, I'd recommend using CAST to convert it into an integer if you are trying to join with another code.